# How to hide and show div by ID based on the value of selected drop down -JQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript I am trying to show/hide the dive based on the grouping value of selected drop down however my below code is not working

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


     $(document).ready(function(){ 

        document.getElementById("Divid").style.display = "none"; //Div I am hiding
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#selectsample').change(function(){
      var val = $(this).val(); // replace $(this) which refer to select box for which change event occurred
      //var $option= $(this).find('option:selected'); -- you can use this option too
      var $option= $(this).find('option[value=' + val + ']');
      var val1 = $option.attr('grouping');

      $("#txt1").val($option.attr(val1));// this is my textfield id=txt1
    }).change();
       if (val1='Yes'){
      document.getElementById("Divid").style.display = "block"; 
}
else{  document.getElementById("Divid").style.display = "none"; }

      });


    </script>
```

my jquery

```
  the div id is ="Divid" this one is the one I wanted to be visible when seleceted is yes
```

and this one

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectsample" name="samp">
    <option value="1" grouping="Yes"  >first</option>
    <option value="2" grouping="No"  >four</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id='txt1'>
```

Comment: No `<div>` shown. Please provide enough relevant html to create a [mcve]

Comment: If you're including jQuery, then *use* jQuery. Don't do `document.getElementById("Divid").style.display = "none";`. Do `$('#Divid').hide()` etc. What's the point of including it if you're not going to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
function ShowHideDiv()
{
    var groupattr = $("option:selected", "#selectsample").attr("grouping");
    if (groupattr == "Yes")
        {
            $("#Divid").show();
        }
    else
        {
            $("#Divid").hide();
        }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Let's run this once in case "Yes" is the default (first) option in the dropdown
        ShowHideDiv();
    $("#selectsample").on("change", function () {
        ShowHideDiv();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go try this !!

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
    $("#selectsample").click(function(){
        var status = $("#selectsample option:selected").attr("grouping");        
        if(status == "Yes"){
          $("#Divid").show();
        }else{
          $("#Divid").hide();
        }
        
    });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectsample" name="samp">
    <option value="1" grouping="Yes"  >first</option>
    <option value="2" grouping="No"  >four</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id='txt1'>
<div id = "Divid">
  the div id is ="Divid" this one is the one I wanted to be visible when seleceted is yes
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Divid').hide();

$('#selectsample').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == "Yes") {
        $('#Divid').show();
    } else {
        $('#Divid').hide();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Few problems with your code...

Firstly you have a nested `$(document).ready` which makes no sense.

Secondly `$("#txt1").val($option.attr(val1));` - This line also makes no sense as you can just do `$("#txt1").val(val1);` and your input will be populated correctly.

Lastly, `if (val1='Yes')` is wrong, a single equals sign is an assignment, comparison is two/three equal signs, to fix it just replace it with `if (val1=='Yes')`.

I am assuming that the div with id "Divid" was just misssed in your example.

Also, as pointed out - a good practise would be to use the provided jQuery methods for selecting elements since you're already using the jQuery framework..

That means element selectors such as:

`document.getElementById("Divid")` can be written in jQuery as `$("#Divid")`.

Notice the leading # symbol that tells jQuery that it's selecting an ID attribute, if you were going to select elements by class you would use a '.' instead however the later would return an array of elements.

Here's a runnable for you...

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#Divid").css("display", "none"); //Div I am hiding can use .hide(); too
 
    $('#selectsample').change(function(){
      var val = $(this).val(); // replace $(this) which refer to select box for which change event occurred
      //var $option= $(this).find('option:selected'); -- you can use this option too
      var $option= $(this).find('option[value=' + val + ']');
      var val1 = $option.attr('grouping');

      $("#txt1").val(val1);// this is my textfield id=txt1
      
      if (val1=='Yes'){
         $("#Divid").css("display", "block"); 
      }else{  
          $("#Divid").css("display", "none"); 
      }
    }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectsample" name="samp">
    <option value="1" grouping="Yes"  >first</option>
    <option value="2" grouping="No"  >four</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id='txt1'>

<div id="Divid" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: blue;">

</div>
```

Comment: Be a lot cleaner to use all jQuery methods or all native methods and help a beginner pick up on best practices

Comment: @charlietfl You're right, I missed that one out on purpose not to modify the original code, however added that in the answer along with explanation. That being said, other answers are not helping the 'beginner' at all to pick up anything, they are just spoon-feeding code with "There you go" yet they are getting upvoted :)

Comment: Understand about last part...good explanation goes a long way though as you have done

Comment: @Aika Great, you're welcome, but please stop changing the accepted answer all the time, you can only have one and you gave it to me 3 times..